# What is the smallest possible dimension for a vector space with a non-degenerate skew-symmetric bilinear form? Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

What is the smallest possible dimension for a vector space with a non-degenerate skew-symmetric bilinear form? Why?

I really don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily construct an example.

Try the bilinear form that takes $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ to $ad-bc$.

Comment: I think you may want to add something about why the dimension can't be $1$.

Comment: @MattSamuel - Well, I figured giving an example of such a form for 2 dimensions would be enough for OP. Analyzing the possibility on 1 dimension is relatively straightforward.

Comment: The bilinear form on a zero-dimensional space is non-degenerate according to the usual definition. (That is, if $B(\vec u,\vec v)=0$ for all $\vec v$, then $\vec u=\vec0$.) So the answer is $0$, not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let´s take space dimension one, then if $S=\{\vec v\}$ is a basis of $V$

$$f(\vec v, \vec v )= -f(\vec v, \vec v )$$
$$f(\vec v, \vec v )= f(-\vec v, \vec v )$$

so $\vec v =-\vec v$ so $\vec v=0$,$ \rightarrow\leftarrow$.

Then lest try a dimension 2 vector space,with base  $S=\{\vec v , \vec w\}$   then let us define the bilinear form as $f(\vec v, \vec w)=a$, and $f(\vec w, \vec v)=-a$  then $$f(\vec w, \vec v)=-f(\vec v, \vec w)$$.

So it can be of $dim=2$.

Representing the bilinear transformation as a matrix $B$ such that $f(\vec v, \vec w)=\vec vB\vec w$, take the $B= \left[\begin{array}{l}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right]$, then $B^T=-B$.